# iPhone - When does a deprecated method usually becomes obsolete?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, deprecated, obsolete

I'm using some methods in some apps that are now marked as deprecated since iOS5. I'd like to know when these updates will become urgent.

So, usually, when does a deprecated method becomes obsolete ? Is there a chance that this will be with iOS 5.1 ? Or is this always with a major version like iOS 6.0 ?

Comment: I always perceived _deprecated_ and _obsolete_ as synonyms :) On the topic: I have no idea really, but note that some APIs deprecated since iOS 2.0 (just check out NSFileManager) are still around...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends and changes from method to method and property to property. If you look at something like the

```
cell.textColor
```

it has been deprecated since iOS 3.0 and can still be used. So unfortunately there's not a specific answer to the general thing about stuff being deprecated.

Comment: You cannot conclude from a single example that there's no rule. It could be they've never removed a method, and the rule is, "Deprecate but never remove." If you showed that there are some methods that HAVE been removed then you could at least say it's not a context-independent rule, but you still wouldn't know whether there are, e.g., simple conditions that Apple follows, such as "Remove properties after 4 releases, methods after 6."

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, no published API has actually been removed from iOS yet, but that's no reason to be complacent. There's no reason to keep using deprecated methods as long as the replacement is available in all the versions of iOS that you need to support.

As for when they'll actually be removed, that's entirely speculation. Keep an eye on the release notes for new versions as they become available. My guess is that they'd only remove them in a major release but there are no guarantees...

Answer (score 3):

For the most part, its in Apple's favor to keep backward-compatibility with older apps.

So when they finally do cut something out, it will be because maintaining it has gotten too expensive or because maintaining it would make adding some new feature difficult or impossible.  (And that reasoning might include cutting deprecated code out because the system is getting too big to fit into the device.)

A better reason to avoid using deprecated methods is the app approval process.  Apple may require new submissions to avoid deprecated code well in advance of actually cutting out that code.